# A Stokes' Theorem problem.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I know this is Stokes' Theorem.

How should I proceed to proof that by dotting a constant vector on both sides I get the answer   .
$\phi$ is a scalar.

---

**Prove** 
$$
\oint_C\phi\,\mathrm d\mathbf r = \iint_S\mathrm d\mathbf S\times\nabla \phi
$$

Comment: Excuse me, but what is your question?

Comment: @fantasie i wanna prove this.